# Using volatile to avoid race conditions

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm learning about `java.util.concurrent`. I wrote some code like this:

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;

public class JUCArrayBlockingQueue {

private static ArrayBlockingQueue<String> abq = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(1);
private static volatile int i = 0;
private static volatile int j = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Pop("t1").start();
    new Pop("t2").start();
    new Push("p1").start();
    new Push("p2").start();
}

static class Pop extends Thread {
    public Pop(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        String str;
        try {

            while (++j < 500) {
                str = abq.take();
                System.out.println(j + ">>"
                        + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " take: "
                        + str);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

static class Push extends Thread {
    public Push(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while (i < 500) {
            if (abq.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " t" + i
                    + "  ~")) {
                i++;
            }
            ;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And the result is like this:

```
488>>t1 take: p2 t486  ~
489>>t2 take: p2 t487  ~
490>>t2 take: p1 t488  ~
491>>t1 take: p1 t489  ~
492>>t1 take: p2 t490  ~
493>>t1 take: p1 t490  ~
494>>t2 take: p1 t492  ~
495>>t2 take: p1 t493  ~
496>>t1 take: p1 t494  ~
497>>t2 take: p1 t495  ~
498>>t1 take: p1 t496  ~
499>>t2 take: p1 t497  ~
500>>t1 take: p2 t498  ~
```

I am puzzled by this output because the left size is expected, but not the right size. I was not expecting duplicate values to be shown on the right side. How can I fix it? Anyone help?

Comment: Well what *did* you expect, and why? Note that `j++` and `i++` aren't thread-safe (because they're not atomic operations), even though the variables are volatile. You should look at `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: Not related to the question but why do you feel the need to extend `Thread` instead of implementing `Runnable`

Comment: @JonSkeet I could be wrong but the issue here is not because the OP did not use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: @bot: Well I don't know what the OP is trying to achieve or what they're expecting, so it's hard to tell - but the use of `i++` from multiple threads *is* a bug.

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed. But there is a possibility of two threads seeing the same value of `i` even before `i++` is called so using an `AtomicInteger` in my opinion won't solve the issue.

Comment: @bot: And that's why I left it as a note rather than an answer. I would suggest that sticking to using `i++` and `j++` without synchronization, just moving them around, *also* won't solve the issue. But until we know what the OP was expecting, we can't really know how broken the code is...

Comment: @JonSkeet Fair enough, fixing this issue is not possible without knowing what the OP wants to achieve but it looks like the OP was expecting the threads to behave and not jump around.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at the code snippet that prints the right hand side of your output :

```
if (abq.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " t" + i
                    + "  ~")) {
       i++;
 }
```

Let's zoom into the condition in the if statement :

```
abq.offer(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " t" + i
                        + "  ~")
```

So you are using the offer method. Let's take a look at the java doc for the offer method :

> public boolean offer(E e)
>
> Inserts the specified element at the tail of
>   this queue if it is possible to do so immediately without exceeding
>   the queue's capacity, returning true upon success and false if this
>   queue is full. This method is generally preferable to method add(E),
>   which can fail to insert an element only by throwing an exception.

Call to offer does not seem to be a blocking call. This means that multiple threads can call the offer method at the same time. This is what is most likely the problem :

1. `t1` offers an element to the `ArrayBlockingQueue`. `i = 0`
2. `p2` immediately takes the element from the queue. `i = 0`
3. `t2` offers an element to the `ArrayBlockingQueue` even before `t1` gets a chance to call `i++`. `i=0`.
4. `p2` immediately takes the element from the queue. `i = 0`.

You can see from 2) and 4) that there is a possibility that two threads read the value of `i` even before `i++` is called and thus see the same value of `i`.

So how do you fix this problem? As others have suggested, you can use `AtomicInteger` as explained below :

The volatile keyword will ensure that when a read **`or`** a write on a variable (memory location) shared across multiple threads is done, it is guaranteed that each Thread will see the latest value of the variable. Notice the emphasis on **`or`**. When you say `i++` or `j++`, you are doing a read **`and`** a write together. This is not an atomic operation and the `volatile` keyword will not stop threads from seeing inconsistent values.

Change

```
private static volatile int i = 0;
```

To :

```
private static final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger();
```

`AtomicInteger` provides the atomic increment operations `incrementAndGet()` (=`++i`) and `getAndIncrement()` (=`i++`) which can be used in this case:

```
int nr=0; // local holder for message number
while ((nr = i.getAndIncrement()) < 500) {
    abq.put(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " t" + nr + "  ~");
}
```

(1) Note the usage of the local variable `nr`! It ensures that the result of the increment operation is used as the message number in `put(...)`. If we used `i` directly instead of `nr`, other threads could have incremented `i` in the meantime and we would have a different message number or a duplicate message number as well!

(2) Also note that `offer(...)` is replaced by `put(...)`. As your queue is bounded (to **1** element only), the insert operation should block if it runs out of capacity. (`offer(...)` will immediately return `false` in that case.)

(3) Note that this code does NOT ensure correct insertion order according to the message number. It only ensures that there are no duplicates! If correct insertion order is required, you will have to use a completely different approach without `AtomicInteger` and `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Instead use a non-thread-safe queue and use good old `synchronized` to make increment and insertion atomic:

```
while (true) {
    synchronized(queue) {
        if (i++ >= 500) break;
        queue.put(... + i + ...);
    }
}
```

The above code is not efficient. Almost the entire code is synchronized. There is no real parallel execution and concurrency is useless.

You can change `j` in a similar fashion.

Comment: I agree. You should also post a hint how to solve this issue. (e.g. using `AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()`)

Comment: Your edit still explains the reason why the current code does NOT work, but not exactly, how to fix it. Possibly you should provide a code snippet. (It is easier to fix if you assume that the order of message writes doesn't matter.)

Comment: @isnot2bad I thought the use of `AtomicInteger` was self explanatory. Anyway, edited the answer with a code snippet.

Comment: You just fall into the trap too! As you explained, it is not only about making `i++` volatile, but also about ensuring that `i` does not change between increment and usage in `abq.offer(...)`. But in your code snippet, the other thread might just increment `i` before the first thread can use it.

Comment: @isnot2bad I see I fell for the trap too. I should really be getting back to work now. Do you feel you could contribute to the answer? I am open to edits. Maybe a do while loop? Maybe drop `AtomicInteger` all together and use `synchronized` blocks? I believe using the blocking call `put` should solve the problem.

Comment: it is incredibly hard to do it correct if you want to ensure correct insertion order (according to the message number). But as this restriction is not necessarily given (OP didn't specify), it can be done by simply using a local variable. Note that if correct insertion order is required, having multiple threads will probably be useless as they will have to synchronize in every single iteration.

Comment: @isnot2bad Can you edit my answer with the solution using a local variable?

Comment: @bot I have tried your suggestion.But saddly,it can't work.it will blocking before j increamt to 500..i don't understand it also

Comment: @LeoSherl What you are trying to do is pretty bad. We have tried to explain to you why it happens and possible ways to fix it. Bottom line is that your example just doesn't make sense if you don't want any concurrency in the first place.

Comment: @isnot2bad Thanks for the edit. You are right. This example does not need concurrency in the first place if it wants to maintain the order of insertion. Sadly, most beginners get a lot of joy from making threads behave when that's not the point of threads in the first place.

Comment: @LeoSherl You're right, it blocks. I haven't noticed that you are using a bounded queue that accepts less than 500 items. In that case, you must use put instead of offer. See my edits.

Comment: @bot I think you are right.Just a practise when i am learning about java.util.concurrent.  Actually This example does not need concurrency.I will think about it and use right condition.

Comment: @LeoSherl Yup. Threads don't like behaving. You can make them behave to some extent and they will still not complain. Asking them to stop being threads is really unfair on your part.

Comment: @isnot2bad3 you are right.but i kown why i use offer because peek() and put() can't work.  when use take() and put(),it can run on right way.

Comment: @LeoSherl I don't fully understand what you want to say. At least, it works with `put()` instead of `offer()` - that's for sure, I've run it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Making a variable volatile does not protect it from race conditions,  it just indicates that the object to which the variable is bound may mutate to prevent compiler optimizations, it is not needed in your case because I & j are modified in the same thread (the loop thread).  To overcome the race condition you need to make the `i++`and `j++` action atomic by synchronization,  like defining them as atomic integer and using `incrementAndGet()`.

Comment: I disagree! Ensuring atomic operations won't stop two threads from seeing the same value of  `i` before `i` is incremented. See my answer.

Comment: That is a rather crude simplification, writes to volatile also (and more importantly) provides certain visibility guarantees in the Java Memory Model, see [JLS 17.4 Memory Model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)

Comment: @bot, edited my answer accordingly. That was my initial intention.